# How to stop requestLocationUpdates() after a certain amount of time?

Tags: android, gps, google-api, location, handler

In my Android application I use `GoogleApiClient` to work with the location service. Everything works well when I call `requestLocationUpdates()` in the following way:

```
locationProvider.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, (LocationListener) thisFragment);
```

where `mGoogleApiClient` is initialized in `onCreate()` method of my activity:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
[...]

// onCreate() method in my activity
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    .addScope(new Scope("email"))
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
```

while `locationProvider` and `locationRequest` are initialized in `onAttach()` method of my fragment that also implements `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`:

```
//onAttach() method in my fragment
this.locationProvider = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;

this.locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
this.locationRequest
    .setInterval(Constants.GOOGLE_LOCATION_INTERVAL)
    .setFastestInterval(Constants.GOOGLE_FASTEST_LOCATION_INTERVAL)
    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

The problem is that, sometimes, a user can ask for retrieving her location in an indoor environment, so I'd like to terminate the `requestLocationUpdates()` request after a certain amount of time.

So far, I've tried the following solutions, but without success:

1) **Using a Looper and a Handler**. Actually this solution worked well with the old `LocationManager`.

```
Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
Handler handler = new Handler(looper);

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
        locationProvider.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, (LocationListener) thisFragment, looper);
    }
}, Constants.LOCATION_TIMEOUT_MS);
```

2) **Using only the Handler**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
        locationProvider.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, (LocationListener) thisFragment);
    }
}, Constants.LOCATION_TIMEOUT_MS);
```

However, in both the two cases, the timeout (expressed by `Constants.LOCATION_TIMEOUT_MS`) never expires. The GPS service keeps working endlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all those two codes are identical:

```
Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
```

and

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

if you check the source code you can see that the empty constructor for Handler internally uses `Looper.myLooper();`

I'm not sure where you think this could would be cancelling a request, after the time passes, you are calling `requestLocationUpdates` again. So yes, it will keep trying to get GPS lock.

I'll suggest you two methods how you should be doing.

1. This first one is easier but I'm not sure how well it works, as I only used it for passive location updates. Use the `expiration` on your request, after that expirated time, the location services should quit automatically.

   ```
   locationRequest.setExpirationDuration(Constants.LOCATION_TIMEOUT_MS);
   ```
2. This second is to use the correct method, which is `removeLocationUpdates`

   ```
   locationProvider.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, 
                (LocationListener) thisFragment);
   ```

Comment: OMG! I need a holiday... You're definitely right! I was calling ``requestLocationUpdates`` instead of ``removeLocationUpdates`` within the handler... Thank you for the information about the constructor of the handler.

Comment: LOL. We all being on that spot that a holiday is needed but not available. Also give a try on the `setExpirationDuration` (might be a nicer approach) and don't forget to `removeLocationUpdates` when fragment `onStop` or else you might be leaking some memory.

Comment: @Budius do you have a source for this statement? "[...] after that expirated time, the location services should quit automatically". I've been trying to figure out exactly what happens at expiry, but have not seen anything definitive yet. Thanks!

Comment: @stkent the name of the method is `setExpirationDuration`, so after the duration, it expires.